# Amazon S3 copy multipart with destination equal to source

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy, multipart, aws-java-sdk

I'm working with AWS Java SDK, specifically to interact with a S3 bucket.

Since I read that S3 does not support the append operation, I'm trying to implement myself a form of append.

Basically my idea is to:
 - store into my S3 bucket a file with the contents to append;
 - use multipart-copy to copy the original S3 object into a destination object;
 - use multipart-copy to copy the object with the contents to append into the same destination file;

Can directly use the original file as the destination file?

Comment: I have heard of people doing exactly this, so apparently it is a feasible idea!

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein! By the way,  do you happen to know why S3 does not support append? It is quite frustrating...

Comment: As an Object Store, the smallest unit of storage is an object. Think of it like a Key-Value store, where the Key is the filename and the Value is the file contents. Appending contents is really storing a different Value against the Key, so the whole Value needs to be stored again. This is similar to a database -- there is no command to append a value to a field, the SQL would always need to reference the current value PLUS the new part. Feel free to lodge your Feedback within the S3 console -- most features added on AWS come from customer feedback!